# Type reference cannot find type named..... NOT because of missing assembly name

Tags: c#, wpf

Just to get this clear ahead of time, I am well aware of the abundance of questions and answers regarding this error that are due to missing assembly names in the declaration, that is not the case here.

I have been seeing some pretty serious instability in the past couple days with code that would seemingly by itself stop compiling throwing errors that were untrue, then magically start working again after closing then re-opening VS, have also had my custom controls stop showing up in the designer and spit out phantom errors in the ctor() then fix themselves and dependency properties in my controls go missing from the VS properties explorer but still be accessible from XAML.... Im wondering if possibly im surfacing some sort of bug in VS, it's happened before when I discovered bugs in VS causing my g.cs files to break...

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Type reference cannot find type named
>   '{clr-namespace:ODIF;assembly=PluginInterface}Global'.    CustomControls_WinX86   xxxxxxxxx\CustomControls_WinX86\ChannelBoxMenu.xaml 17

Complete XAML for my user control:

```
UserControl x:Name="ChannelBoxMenuControl" x:Class="CustomControls_WinX86.ChannelBoxMenu"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomControls_WinX86"
             xmlns:ODIF="clr-namespace:ODIF;assembly=PluginInterface"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="250">
    <Grid>
        <Menu x:Name="menu">
            <MenuItem x:Name="menuItem" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Template="{DynamicResource MarginlessMenuItem}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=menu, Mode=OneWay}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=menu, Mode=OneWay}" >
                <MenuItem.Header>
                    <local:ChannelBox Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=menuItem, Mode=OneWay}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=menuItem, Mode=OneWay}" Channel="{Binding SelectedChannel, ElementName=ChannelBoxMenuControl}"/>
                </MenuItem.Header>
                <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static  ODIF:Global.ConnectedDevices}, Mode=OneWay}"><!--THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS THROWN-->
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding StatusIcon}" Width="16" Height="16">
                                <Image.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Icon}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Image.Style>
                            </Image>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DeviceName}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the relevant code from my referenced assembly:

```
namespace ODIF
{
    public static class Global
    {
        internal static GlobalStore Store = new GlobalStore();
        public static AsyncObservableCollection<InputDevice> ConnectedDevices
        {
            get
            {
                return Store.inputDevices;
            }
        }
    }
    internal class GlobalStore
    {
        internal AsyncObservableCollection<InputDevice> inputDevices;
    }
}
```

Also worth noting that when I begin typing in the path for the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` ItemsSource, intellisense picks up the path ODIF:Global.ConnectedDevices just fine and auto completes it, but then throws error that it cannot find it....

Comment: Sounds to me like possibly a corrupted install of VS. Have you tried re-installing?

Comment: Just updated to 2015.1 this morning after having getting fed up with the other issues I mentioned, though all was good until this latest round of errors. Seems a complete uninstall and re-install may be needed, but that takes sooooo long.

Comment: And of course somebody does a drive by downvote without bothering to read the fact that this is not like the other questions regarding this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really an explanation as to why the above won't work, as best I can tell it should. But a workaround for me if anybody comes across the same issue is to create a static property in the UserControl's class that references the static property in the other assembly:

Added to ChannelBoxMenu : UserControl

```
    public static AsyncObservableCollection<ODIF.InputDevice> ConnectedDevices
    {
        get
        {
            return Global.ConnectedDevices;
        }
    }
```

And modified my binding to read:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ConnectedDevices, ElementName=ChannelBoxMenuControl}
```

It's not as clean as the direct reference, but it has the benefit of working.

Comment: Would still love to know why the code in the original question was no good however.